# Issues with notation

Tags: functions, notation

I have this definition, and I am having difficulties with notation:

[image]

Maybe I should explain a little bit: $D_{1}$ and $D_{2}$ are two matrices (or databases) with the same number of columns, but $D_{2}$ has 1 additional element that isn't in $D_{1}$ (or vice versa).

So what does $\Delta f$ actually do? What does the "||" mean and what does it mean to have 1 at the end (i.e. $||_{1}$)? What if it was 2 or 3 ?

Comment: The function $\| \cdot \|_k$ generally denotes the $\ell^k$ (or $L^k$) norm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|| \cdot ||_1$ is standard notation for the $L^1$ norm, i.e. $||f||_1 = \int |f| dx$, more generally $||f||_k = (\int |f|^k dx)^{1/k}$ is the $L^k$ norm. So your sensitivity simply measures the integral of the absolute value of the difference between $f(D_1)$ and $f(D_2)$, taken over all possible $D_1$ and $D_2$.